# issue in enabling proguard using SMAATO ads

Tags: android, proguard, ads

I am implementing proguards in my app also added ads using SMAATO but I am getting the following error:

```
proguard.ParseException: Unexpected keyword 'classmembers'
```

I have added following lines as per [SMAATO documentation:](https://wiki.smaato.com/display/SPX/Android):

```
-dontwarn com.mopub.**
-keep public class * extends one.mopub.*
-keep class com.mopub.** { *; }
-keep classmembers class com.millennialmedia** {
public *;
}
-keep class com.millennialmedia**
-keep public class com.smaato.soma.internal.connector.OrmmaBridge {
public *;
}
-keepattributes *Annotation
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> -keepclasseswithmembers class pkg.yourclass
>   or -keepclassmembers class pkg.yourclass

Answer (score 0):

There is an additional space in this line that causes this parse error:

```
-keep classmembers class com.millennialmedia** {
```

The keep rule must be written as one word like this (additionally, I would add a seperator dot before the wildcard for clarity):

```
-keepclassmembers class com.millennialmedia.** {
```